# Shopify returning "topic can't be blank" for webhook POST even though I'm supplying one

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a webhook here:

```
curl --header "X-Shopify-Access-Token: <token>" -d '{"webhook": {"topic": "orders/create", "address": "http://www.google.com/", "format": "json"}}' https://test-store-402.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json
```

Here's the JSON pretty-printed for readability:

```
{
    "webhook": {
        "topic": "orders/create",
        "address": "http://www.google.com/",
        "format": "json"
    }
}
```

It's returning this error:

```
{"errors":{"topic":["can't be blank","Invalid topic specified. Topics allowed: orders/create, orders/updated, orders/paid, orders/cancelled, orders/fulfilled, orders/partially_fulfilled, app/uninstalled, customer_groups/create, customer_groups/update, customer_groups/delete, products/create, products/update, products/delete, collections/create, collections/update, collections/delete, carts/create, carts/update"],"address":["can't be blank"]}}
```

I've confirmed:

- The spelling of the topic is correct
- The JSON request payload is wrapped in "webhook" (singular) correctly, as per the [docs](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html)
- I've copied and pasted the JSON into jsonlint.com to sanity check that the JSON is valid

Confused...didn't see any other questions on SO related to this specifically, I must be doing something terribly obvious wrong - or else everyone would be hitting this issue.

**UPDATE**: I got it to work over command-line by passing in the `Content-type: application/json` header.  But now I'm having problems over `curl_exec` in PHP.  I have the following CURLOPT's set:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER: false
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION: true
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS: 10
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST: 'POST'
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: array {
    0 => string 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: <token>'
    1 => string 'Content-type: application-json' (length=30)
```

Note that I can do GET's just fine over `curl` - only POSTs returning this confusing response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work in curl_exec.  Here's what I'm using:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER: false
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION: true
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS: 10
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST: 'POST'
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: array {
    0 => string 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: <token>'
    1 => string 'Content-type: application-json' (length=30)
CURLOPT_POSTDATA: '{"webhook":{"topic":"orders/updated","address":"http://www.google.com","format":"json"}}'
```

I think the problem may have been that I left out the CURLOPT_POSTDATA in my Update above.